# 00936. 00000 - "missing expression" CAST EXPRESSION

Tags: ora-00936

I am trying to change a date format on a column labeled ADDED_DATE.

the current results are 30-FEB-17 I wanted to convert to mm/dd/yyyy

I tried using the statement below but it is giving me an error.

```
CAST(varchar(10), cast  (ADDED_DATE AS date) , 101) ,
```

> ORA-00936: missing expression
>   00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do directly this:

```
to_date(ADDED_DATE,'DD/MM/YYYY');
```

Comment: It gives me a different error if I try the above.

ORA-01843: not a valid month
01843. 00000 -  "not a valid month"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: @MHernandez I updated the answer, try again but with 'DD/MM/YYYY' instead 'MM/DD/YYYY'

Comment: now I get the error below

ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
01858. 00000 -  "a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected"
*Cause:    The input data to be converted using a date format model was
           incorrect.  The input data did not contain a number where a number was
           required by the format model.
*Action:   Fix the input data or the date format model to make sure the
           elements match in number and type.  Then retry the operation.

Answer (score 0):

needed to add To_char

TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('01-JAN-16','DD-MON-YY'),'MM/DD/YYYY')